# button is causing input fields to move up on hover (on chrome)

Tags: html, css

Whenever I move my mouse over one of the input fields it goes up a bit, but this doesn't happen with firefox, just chrome.

here is a snippet of the problem.

```css
span {
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

.add__container1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  position: relative;
}

.Exponent-1,
.Exponent-2,
.Exponent-3 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
  width: 15px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.Operator2,
.Operator1 {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  /*padding: 12px 15px;*/
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: border 0.3s;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.r1s-delete-btn {
  font-size: 35px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.r1s-delete-btn:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.r1s-delete-btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.up-arrow-btn:focus,
.down-arrow-btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<div class="add__container1">
  <button class="r1s-delete-btn"><ion-icon name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon></button>

  <span class="span">____
     <input type="number" placeholder="" class="Exponent-1">
   </span>

  <select class="Operator1">
    <option value="+" selected>+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="*">x</option>
    <option value="/">/</option>
  </select>
  <span class="span">____
     <input type="number" placeholder="" class="Exponent-2">
   </span>

  <select class="Operator2">
    <option value="+" selected>+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="*">x</option>
    <option value="/">/</option>
  </select>
  <span class="span">____
     <input type="number" placeholder="" class="Exponent-3">    
   </span>
  <span>=</span>
</div>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
```

and this a link to a jsfiddle of it https://jsfiddle.net/JohnDipiazza/ykq724xf/26/

when I remove the button the problem doesn't happen anymore, but I really need the button there...

any help is appreciated.

Comment: Don't place your entire code in, doing so may cause users to ignore your problem. If you have the link to the entirety of the code, just show the areas that you think might have a problem. Good luck with finding an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by making the `.span` parent elements `display: inline-block`.

```
<span class="span">____
  <input type="number" placeholder="" class="Exponent-1">
</span>
```

```css
span {
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.add__container1 {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10vh;
  position: relative;
}

.Exponent-1,
.Exponent-2,
.Exponent-3 {
  position: absolute;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  outline: none;
  width: 15px;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  background: transparent;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  bottom: 20px;
}

.Operator2,
.Operator1 {
  color: inherit;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 14px;
  /*padding: 12px 15px;*/
  margin-right: 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  transition: border 0.3s;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.r1s-delete-btn {
  font-size: 35px;
  background: none;
  border: none;
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
}

.r1s-delete-btn:active {
  transform: translateY(2px);
}

.r1s-delete-btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.up-arrow-btn:focus,
.down-arrow-btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}

input[type=number] {
  -moz-appearance: textfield;
}
```

```html
<div class="add__container1">
  <button class="r1s-delete-btn"><ion-icon name="close-circle-outline"></ion-icon></button>

  <span class="span">____
     <input type="number" placeholder="" class="Exponent-1">
   </span>

  <select class="Operator1">
    <option value="+" selected>+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="*">x</option>
    <option value="/">/</option>
  </select>
  <span class="span">____
     <input type="number" placeholder="" class="Exponent-2">
   </span>

  <select class="Operator2">
    <option value="+" selected>+</option>
    <option value="-">-</option>
    <option value="*">x</option>
    <option value="/">/</option>
  </select>
  <span class="span">____
     <input type="number" placeholder="" class="Exponent-3">    
   </span>
  <span>=</span>
</div>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v7zmfu52/)